# Read txt file from assets folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to read a .txt from the assets folder in eclipse. I have this code:

```
void LecturaModelos(){
    int N = 1716;
    double[] vector = new double[N];
    double[][] matriz = new double[13][N/13];
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File("/assets/Modelos1.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String line = inputStream.next();
            vector[i] =(double) Double.parseDouble(line);
    }
    inputStream.close(); 
}
```

But I get this error:

> 04-04 16:42:08.358: E/AndroidRuntime(9707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-04 16:42:08.358: E/AndroidRuntime(9707):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.ejemplo.lecturaficheros/com.ejemplo.lecturaficheros.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException

I think that could be because I need some permission but I don't know which one it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `/assets/Modelos1.txt` on any Android device on the planet.

To access assets, use `getAssets().open("Modelos1.txt")`, called on any `Context`, such as your `Activity`.